# Java's pattern matcher says no match found but matches are print to the console

Tags: java, regex

I've written a matcher to match from the following text.

```
<TD><P>xyz...  </P><P>Oiuye </P><P>Oture, </P><P>Option</P></TD><TD><P> EUR 0.20 </P></TD><Span></Span>     
<TD><P>Foriegn </P></TD><TD><P> EUR 0.30 </P></TD><Span></Span>
```

The Pattern I want to use is:-

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\</TD\\>\\<TD\\>\\<P\\>(.*?)\\</P\\>");Matcher m_Fee_1 = p_Fee_1.matcher(row_xml);          
m_Fee_1.find();
String Contract_Fee_Temp = m_Fee_1.group(1).trim();
```

I need to capture EUR 0.20 and EUR 0.30.

My console shows
EUR 0.20
EUR 0.30

And throws an Error, No match found. Why does this happen? Is it okay if I just catch that exception and take the data? Or how should I handle it?

Comment: How are you using the matcher?. show us the code.

Comment: As a site note, you don’t need all theses backslashes: `Pattern.compile("</TD><TD><P>(.*?)</P>")` will do as well, simple and readable…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using the matcher incorrectly:

```
    String[] str = new String[]{"<TD><P>xyz...  </P><P>Oiuye </P><P>Oture, </P><P>Option</P></TD><TD><P> EUR 0.20 </P></TD><Span></Span> ", "<TD><P>Foriegn </P></TD><TD><P> EUR 0.30 </P></TD><Span></Span>"};
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\</TD\\>\\<TD\\>\\<P\\>(.*?)\\</P\\>");
    for (String st : str) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(st);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
```

Yields:

```
EUR 0.20 
EUR 0.30
```

Comment: He wants to match `EUR 0.30` also

Comment: @AvinashRaj: The code also worked for the second example. I had omitted it to avoid clutter. Anyways, I have updated the answer to include both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You just can catch the exception if you are already getting what you require.

```
try{
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\</TD\\>\\<TD\\>\\<P\\>(.*?)\\</P\\>");Matcher m_Fee_1 = p_Fee_1.matcher(row_xml);          
m_Fee_1.find();
String Contract_Fee_Temp = m_Fee_1.group(1).trim(); 
//Print what ever you want
}
catch(IllegalStateException exception){}
```